# How Gazebo generate heigthmaps?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello;

I'm trying to create a plugin , that , given a x,y coordinates, set the position of a model in the ground level of a heigthmap. I generate it  through a greyscale image (following this tutorial: https://github.com/AS4SR/general_info/wiki/Creating-Heightmaps-for-Gazebo). Does anybody know how gazebo generate the 3D surface from this grayscale image.

I use Gazebo 7 in ubuntu 16.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19463/how-gazebo-generate-heigthmaps?/) by [Mansan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4773/mansan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 68 on 2018-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You mean how does Gazebo internally transform the image into a collision shape? If so, take a look at [gazebo::physics::HeightmapShape](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1HeightmapShape.html#details). [Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/8bc98f4cf031fd36cae049fe2c90a072aeaf84a5/gazebo/physics/HeightmapShape.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#HeightmapShape.cc-83)'s the source code.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mansan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4773/mansan/) on 2018-05-24**:
Thaks! The  GetHeight function is just what I needed.